# Изменение Item в LiveData<List>

Tags: android, kotlin

мне необходимо, чтобы метод менял один из объектов в LiveData>

```
private var records : LiveData<List<Record>> =  repository.getAllRecording()

fun handleSelectedItem(id : Int){
        val items = records.value?.map {
            if(it.id == id) it.copy(isSelected = !it.isSelected)
            else it
        }

        records.value = items ///не работает
}
```

`items` это `List<Record>`. Как мне обратно к типу `LiveData<List<Record>>` привести?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать `MutableLiveData`:

```
private var records : MutableLiveData<List<Record>> =  repository.getAllRecording()

fun handleSelectedItem(id : Int){
        val items = records.value?.map {
            if(it.id == id) it.copy(isSelected = !it.isSelected)
            else it
        }

        records.value = items ///не работает
}
```